# How to execute a function out of an included class

Tags: c++, function, class

I got two classes separated in four files. The main class includes a sub class and needs to execute functions of it (not shown in the minimal example code). What I want to do is to execute a function of the main class in the scope of the subclass.

I think some ideas would be to inherit the functions in the sub class but I could not figure out how to do this.

MainClass.cpp

```cpp
#include "MainClass.hpp"

void MainClass::mainCallback() {
  std::cout << "[mainCallback] executed" << std::endl;
}

void MainClass::subCallback() {
  std::cout << "[subCallback] executed" << std::endl;
}

int main() {

  MainClass mainClass;
  mainClass.mainCallback();

  SubClass subClass;
  subClass.activateSubClass();

  return 0;
}
```

MainClass.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "SubClass.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class MainClass{
 public:
  void mainCallback();
  void subCallback();
};
```

SubClass.cpp

```cpp
#include "SubClass.hpp"

void SubClass::activateSubClass(){
 mainClass.subCallback(); //TODO call this function from this scope
}
```

SubClass.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

class SubClass{
 public:
  void activateSubClass();
};
```

The error in SubClass.cpp is of course: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'mainClass'

Comment: *On which instance* of `MainClass` do you want `mainClass.subCallback();` to call the callback? Or maybe you don't need *any* instance and could make the callback `static`?

Comment: "not shown in the minimal example code" Please make it a [mcve]. It is important to know the whole tree of file inclusion. Also, is there a typo somewhere around the mainClass vs. MainClass capitalisation? It would be a hard to notice (except for a compiler) source of problems if the not shown code has a problem here.

Comment: I get this that it would work when `mainClass` is a member variable of `SubClass`. So I just need to include the files in the right order I guess. Let me go trough it again.
@Yunnosch the point of not showing the functions was just to point out that the subclass has to be the subclass and can not simply include the `mainClass`

Comment: Not include, not member variable. Read up on inheriting.

Comment: Instead of having "irrelvant" code parts and not showing them, please make a MCVE which does not need them. The problem is otherwise that askers here far too often misjudge what is relevant and what is not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subclass the subclass:

```
class SubClass: public MainClass {
 public:
  void activateSubClass();
};
```

This (public) way the SubClass makes all methods of MainClass callable in SubClass instances. You could also private inherit. That way only activateSubClass() 'ld be callable.

In activateSubClass you can call directly the methods of the parent class:

```
void SubClass::activateSubClass(){
 mainClass.subCallback(); //TODO call this function from this scope
}
```

Don't forget to include MainClass.hpp in SubClass.hpp

Comment: Note OPs comment on the question (should be here). Your answer seems to need more explanation. Stress and highlight the inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I do this I get circular dependencies, right? I'm including the `MainClass.hpp` in `SubClass.hpp` and also the opposite. I get the error: `expected class name` for the inheritance because the `#pragma once` prevents including the `MainClass.hpp` in `SubClass.hpp`

Comment: Okay I solved it. The problem was, that the `SubClass.hpp` was still included in `MainClass.hpp. Now I can access the function. 
Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You try to call a `MainClass.subCallback()` without having an instance of `MainClass`. According to me, this is the typical use case for `static` methods.

Then, I think you make your `#include` directives the wrong way. Indeed, `MainClass` does not seem to need to know `SubClass` but the opposite is true. I think it is better to include MainClass.hpp in SubClass.hpp. This will solve your circle dependencies problem.
And you can write your `main()` function in another file.

---

**EDIT: Example**

*MainClass.hpp*:

```
#pragma once
class MainClass
{
   public:
      void mainCallback();
      static void subCallback(); // mak it static to be able to call it without an instance of the class
};
```

*MainClass.cpp*:

```
#include "MainClass.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void MainClass::mainCallback()
{
   std::cout << "[mainCallback] executed" << std::endl;
}
void MainClass::subCallback()
{
   std::cout << "[subCallback] executed" << std::endl;
}
```

*SubClass.hpp*:

```
#pragma once
class SubClass
{
   public:
      void activateSubClass();
};
```

*SubClass.cpp*:

```
#include "SubClass.hpp"
#include "MainClass.hpp" // MainClass inclusion

void Suclass::activateSubClass()
{
   MainClass::subCallback(); // Call of the static method
}
```

*main.cpp*:

```
#include "MainClass.hpp"
#include "SubClass.hpp"

int main()
{
   MainClass mc;
   mc.mainCallback();

   SubClass sc;
   sc.activateSubClass(); // Will call MainClass::subCallback()

   return 0;
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I do not know a lot about static methods yet and will look them up. Including the `SubClass.hpp` in `MainClass.hpp` is necessary, as there are some functions that need to be called this way.

Comment: @dofrey I made an edit to my answer to give you an example.

Comment: Ah ok, but regarding only the code you showed, the `MainClass` does not need to know the `SubClass`. You just have to write the `main()` in another file that includes what you want.